# How do I access a constant defined in a header file?

Tags: c++

The following is my .h

```
#ifndef GRID_H_
#define GRID_H_

#include <array>


namespace game{

class Grid{
public:
    static const int dimension = 10;
    std::array<int, dimension*dimension> grid;

    Grid();

    int get_cell(int x, int y);



};

} 

#endif /* GRID_H_ */
```

The following is my .cpp

```
#include "Grid.h"

namespace game {

Grid::Grid() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


int get_cell(int i, int j){
    return (std::get<(i*dimension+j)>grid);
}
}
```

Compiler says:

error: `'dimension' was not declared in this scope`.

I tried to add the scope resolution operator game`::`, but it didn't work. How can I access this constant from the header file?

Shouldn't it be a global public variable?! And the include should copy and paste the code from the header file. I don;t understand what's wrong. Sorry for the basic question; I'm new to C++/

Comment: I don't understand, where did you define Grid::dimension? shouldn't you define "static const int Grid::dimension = 10" in the .cpp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the class name to access a `static` member:

```
int Grid::get_cell(int i, int j){
  return (std::get<(i* Grid::dimension +j)>grid);
}
```

**Note:** `::` operator refers to *global scope*. But `dimension` is in class scope, not global.

Your usage of `std::get` is wrong. It should be

```
 return (std::get< /*a constant value*/>(grid)); //
```

Comment: Compiler now says: error: expected ')' before 'grid'
error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'get' based on conversion to type 'int'

Comment: It refers to `(std::get<(i* Grid::dimension +j)>grid)` line, you are not using `std::get` correctly.

Comment: Do you know how Im not using it correctly? I changed it to the bracket notation and it works  but Idk what I did wrong with that std::get notation

Comment: After adding the parens to grid, im getting error: no matching function for call to 'get(std::array<int, 100ull>&)' error: 'i' is not a constant expression

Comment: const int index = i*dimension +j; Then return ( std::get<index>(grid) ); results in" the value of 'index' is not usable in a constant expression"

Comment: `const int index = i*dimension +j;` makes `index` constant, but its value can only be computed at runtime, not compile time. you just try with a constant value (like `0`), and see the errors will be gone

Answer (score 2):

```
int get_cell(int i, int j){
    return (std::get<(i*dimension+j)>grid);
}
```

This defines a global function, you could should refer to `dimension` directly:

```
 int get_cell(int i, int j){
    return (std::get<(i* Grid::dimension+j) > grid);
 //                      ^^^^^^
}
```

You should define `get_cell` as a member of `Grid`

```
int Grid::get_cell(int i, int j){
//  ^^^^
    return (std::get<(i*dimension+j)>grid);
}
```